# onclick event is not triggering the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, web

I'm trying make a `nav` bar that when click will trigger a function that will will change the text in right new to it. Right now the `onclick` event does not seem to be triggering.

**HTML**

```
<div id="classOfferingList" class="classOfferingList" align="left">
    <ul>
        <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(1)">TESTANCHOR1</a>    </li>
        <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(2)"> TESTANCHOR2</a>    </li>
        <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(3)">TESTANCHOR3</a>    </li>
        <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(4)">TESTANCHOR4</a>    </li>
        <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(5)">TESTANCHOR5</a>    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="classOfferingInfo">EXAMPLE WRITING</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script language = "Javascript" >
 text1 = "RANDOMTEXT1";
 text2 = "RANDOMTEXT2";
 text3 = "RAMDONTEXT3";
 text4 = "RANDOMTEXT4";
 text5 = "RANODMTEXT5";

 function changeInfo(infoNum) {
     document.getElementById("classOfferingInfo").textContent = window['text' + infoNum];
 }
 </script>
```

I can provide more code if this isn't enough to figure out the problem.

Comment: `changeInfo()` is works fine at my side.

Comment: **Working here =>** http://jsfiddle.net/a83Y2/ `:)`

Comment: Its working fine. 
Just check Javascript should not be disabled in your Browser.

Comment: Hmmm I seem to have everything enabled. I have other JavaScript in another function that works fine.

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine. May be you forget to enable the Javascript in your Browser.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"  >
     text1 = "RANDOMTEXT1";
     text2 = "RANDOMTEXT2";
     text3 = "RAMDONTEXT3";
     text4 = "RANDOMTEXT4";
     text5 = "RANODMTEXT5";

     function changeInfo(infoNum) {
         document.getElementById("classOfferingInfo").textContent = window['text' + infoNum];
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="classOfferingList" class="classOfferingList" align="left">
    <ul>
    <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(1)">TESTANCHOR1</a>    </li>
    <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(2)"> TESTANCHOR2</a>    </li>
    <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(3)">TESTANCHOR3</a>    </li>
    <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(4)">TESTANCHOR4</a>    </li>
    <li>    <a onclick="changeInfo(5)">TESTANCHOR5</a>    </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
<div>
    <p id="classOfferingInfo">EXAMPLE WRITING</p>
</div></body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/AXLVk/)

Comment: Hmmm I seem to have everything enabled. I have other JavaScript in another function that works fine.

Comment: @user3418145, First check the function is called or not. So add alert() method in your changeInfo() function. Also check your browsers console.log. May be you have any error messages in your Console.

Comment: Okay I figure it out. The text I was having printed back on to the screen was mult-lined. I forgot you can't have mult-line in JavaScript. Thanks for the help.